# how to output text to pdf using the same formatting as in the console in python

Tags: python, pdf, console, output

How can I output some text with colours to the console and also write that same text with the same formatting to a PDF file.

for example, I can write coloured text to the console doing something like:

```
print("This text contains some \033[1;31mRED\033[0m and \033[3mITALIC\033[0m words.")
```

the "RED" word in the text will be red, and the ITALIC text will be italic.

But how can I also output that same text to a PDF file to contain the same colours and formatting?

Comment: The print statement works in Linux console, but on Windows "ITALIC" is **not** *ITALIC*.

Comment: you can use the _set_text_color_ [like this](https://pyfpdfbook.wordpress.com/2015/03/17/text-color-using-set_text_color/) function. But you will have to call it multiple times. FPDF module is not that flexible, to consider color codes in text.

Comment: Your question amounts to: which Python package supports output of text that supports embedded styling information. I seem to remember there is something in package [rst2pdf](https://pypi.org/project/rst2pdf/). If you however don't mind using the HTML styling syntax, then PyMuPDF will support you: **'This text contains some <span style="color: red;">RED</span> and <i>ITALIC</i> words.'** will be written as desired.

Comment: Yes i checked FPDF too. I dont mind using any other formating style, what I didnt want is to execute the same task twice. I know i could just print out the text as mentioned in my question and then just rewrite the same text in FPDF or other library to output to a pdf file.
I though maybe there is a library that does that, output and also write to a file